# Given a positive integer $k$, describe all positive integers $n$ such that $\langle n\rangle=k$.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, solution-verification

> Question: For any positive integer $n$, let $\langle n \rangle$ denote the integer nearest to $\sqrt{n}$.
>
> (a) Given a positive integer $k$, describe all positive integers $n$ such that $\langle n\rangle=k$.
>
> (b) Show that $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{2^{\langle n\rangle}+2^{-\langle n\rangle}}{2^n}=3.$$

My approach: It is clear that there are exactly $2n$ integers between $(n+1)^2$ and $n^2$, $\forall n\in\mathbb{N}$. Now, by the pattern that we observe we can conclude that out of these $2n$ integers the first $n$ integers, let us call them $k$, have $\langle k \rangle =n$ and the other $n$ integers, let us call them $l$, have $\langle l\rangle=n+1.$

Therefore, for any $k\in\mathbb{N}$, the positive integers $n$ that have $\langle n\rangle=k$ are $k^2-(k-1), k^2-(k-2),\cdots, k^2, k^2+1, k^2+2, \cdots, k^2+k.$

Therefore, we are done with part (a) of the question.

Now $\forall k\in\mathbb{N}$ we have, $$\sum_{n=k^2-(k-1)}^{k^2+k}\frac{2^{\langle n\rangle}+2^{-\langle n\rangle}}{2^n}\\=\sum_{n=k^2-(k-1)}^{k^2+k}\frac{2^{k}+2^{-k}}{2^n}\\=(2^k+2^{-k})\sum_{n=k^2-(k-1)}^{k^2+k}\frac{1}{2^n}\\=(2^k+2^{-k})\frac{2^{-(k^2-(k-1))}((2^{-1})^{2k}-1)}{2^{-1}-1}\\=(2^k+2^{-k})\frac{2^{k-1-k^2}(2^{-2k}-1)}{2^{-1}-1}\\=(2^k+2^{-k})\frac{2^{-k^2-k-1}-2^{k-1-k^2}}{2^{-1}-1}\\=(2^k+2^{-k})(2^{k-k^2}-2^{-k^2-k})\\=2^{2k-k^2}-2^{-k^2-2k}=2^{1-(k-1)^2}-2^{1-(k+1)^2}=(2^{1-(k-1)^2}+2^{1-k^2})-(2^{1-k^2}+2^{1-(k+1)^2}).$$

Define the sequence $\{a_n\}_n\ge1$, such that $$a_n=2^{1-(n-1)^2}+2^{1-n^2}, \forall n\in\mathbb{N}.$$

Therefore, $\forall k\in\mathbb{N}$ we have, $$\sum_{n=k^2-(k-1)}^{k^2+k}\frac{2^{\langle n\rangle}+2^{-\langle n\rangle}}{2^n}=a_k-a_{k+1}.$$

This implies that $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{2^{\langle n\rangle}+2^{-\langle n\rangle}}{2^n}=\sum_{i=1}^\infty a_i-a_{i+1}=\lim_{l\to\infty}(a_1-a_{l+1})=3.$$

Hence, $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{2^{\langle n\rangle}+2^{-\langle n\rangle}}{2^n}=3.$$

As one can see part (a) of the question is done based on observation and not rigorously. Can someone provide a rigorous solution to part (a) of the question and check if part (b) is done correctly and rigorously or not.

Comment: Consider $ k- \frac{1}{2} \leq \sqrt{n} \leq k + \frac{1}{2}$

Comment: "The nearest integer" is ambiguous for numbers ending with ".5". However, the square of a number ending with ".5" always ends with ".25", so "the nearest integer to $\sqrt{n}$" is always unambiguous.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The condition states that $ k- \frac{1}{2} \leq \sqrt{n} \leq k + \frac{1}{2}$

Squaring, we get

> $ k^2 -k + \frac{1}{4} \leq n \leq k^2 + k + \frac{1}{4}$

Now, use the fact that $n $ is integer to conclude

> $ k^2 - k + 1 \leq n \leq k^2 +k$

---

Your part b) is correct.

---

A nicer solution to b) is to look at what the multiset $\{<n>-n\} \cup \{-<n>-n\}$ is.

> The multiset is $ \{ 0, -1, -1, -2, -2, -3, -3, -4, -4, -5, -5, \ldots \}$.
>  This is supported by OP's observation that

> Therefore, for any $k\in\mathbb{N}$, the positive integers $n$ that have $\langle n\rangle=k$ are $k^2-(k-1), k^2-(k-2),\cdots, k^2, k^2+1, k^2+2, \cdots, k^2+k.$

Hence conclude that

$$\sum_n \frac{ 2^{<n> } + 2^{-<n> }} { 2^n} = \frac{1}{2^0} + 2\times \sum_{i=1}^\infty \frac{1}{2^i} = 1 +  2 = 3.$$

Comment: How do you conclude $k^2 - k + 1 \leq n \leq k^2 +k$ just from the fact that $n\in\Bbb Z$ ? I don't get this ?

Comment: @Franklin Say for $k = 3$, what integers do you know that are between 6.25 and 12.25? Would you say that they are between 7 and 12 (inclusive)? How does this apply to the general case?

Comment: The integers between 6.25 and 12.25 are: 7,8,9,...,12. Yes, that's they are between 7 and 12(inclusive). But how does that apply to the general case ? (That's actually my question )

Comment: Consider the lower bound of $k^2 - k + 1/4$. Since $k^2 - k$ is an integer, say $M$, then $k^2 - k + 1/4 = M.25$, so we can round it up to $M+1 = k^2 - k + 1$. What happens for the upper bound?

Comment: Ohh...like that! I get it. Though, that simplification is optional, but since it provides a more strong bound so that's reasonable. But just another question: your solution for part b,...can you please elaborate your approach ? 

Comment: Why don't you list out the multisets, and see how often each number appears? From the conclusion, it seems to be suggesting that 0 appears once, and each negative integer appears exactly twice, so let's experimentally verify that. $\quad$ If it's true, how can we explain that? Notice that as $n$ increases by 1, $<n> - n$ will decrease by 0 or 1, and $-<n> - n$ will decrease by 1 or 2.